# About Kinect and turtlebot_2

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when testing kinect on turtlebot2
Why I can see image in /camera/depth/image, but there is no data in /camera/rgb/image_color

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240038/about-kinect-and-turtlebot_2/) by [StoneSmart](https://answers.ros.org/users/27559/stonesmart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2016-07-21**:
Info about what package you are using with the kinect would help (e.g. freenect). If you run `rostopic list` do you see the topic `/camera/rgb/image_color`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just try roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch after that run rostopic echo /camera/rgb/image_raw you ll be able to see the data

---

Originally posted by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) with karma: 73 on 2016-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0